# Spring-HateoasTraverson how to get info from three tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have three tables in my database e.g. `user`, `authority` and `role`.
The table authority contains two fields `user_id` and `role_id` that are foreign keys.
The SQL statement is:

```
SELECT t1.id id, t3.id user_id, t3.username_x username_x, t2.id role_id, t2.desc_x desc_x
FROM `securitydashboard`.`authorities` AS t1
INNER JOIN `securitydashboard`.`role` AS t2
INNER JOIN `securitydashboard`.`user` AS t3
ON (t2.id = t1.role_id
AND t3.id = t1.user_id);
```

The result would be:

```
id user_id username_x role_id desc_x
1  1       admin      1       ROLE_ADMIN
2  1       admin      2       ROLE_USER
```

I am setting up the simple Spring-Hateoas project. It will be easier to get the info as above via "sql view" and run on Traverson. 
I am struggling to get the info as above via Traverson without "sql view".
My java program as below is this:

```
public class UserResource extends ResourceSupport {

    public String usernameX;
    public String passwordX;
    public String firstnameX;
    public String lastnameX;
    public EmailAddress emailX;
    public Boolean enabledB;
    public String saltX;
    public AuthoritiesesById authority;

    static class AuthoritiesesById {

        public Roles role;

        static class Roles {
            String descX;
        }
    }
}

public class Test2 {
    private static final     ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Resource<UserResource>>> TYPE_REFERENCE = new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Resource<UserResource>>>() {};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String urlstring = "http://localhost:8085/RestDashboard";
        URL url = new URL(urlstring);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        LinkDiscoverer discoverer = new HalLinkDiscoverer();
        Link link = discoverer.findLinkWithRel("users", connection.getInputStream());

        URI uri = new URI(urlstring);
        Traverson traverson = new Traverson(uri, MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        PagedResources<Resource<UserResource>> resources = traverson.follow(link.getRel()).withTemplateParameters(parameters).toObject(TYPE_REFERENCE);
        for (Resource<UserResource> resource : resources) {
            System.out.print(resource.getContent().authority.role.descX);
        }
    }
}
```

The result returns null.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if it is the problem, but you are extending your `UserResource` from `ResourceSupport` AND you are typing your `TypeReference` with `Resource` which results in the same actually. 
Try it at least either with extending from `ResourceSupport` OR with typing it  with `Resource` but not with both options at once.

UPDATE:

Try to instantiate your type reference with `org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.TypeReferences.PagedResourcesType`